# Lot no longer has a pool; Sims still want to swim, get stuck in loop

Tags: the-sims-3

My current household used to contain a swimming pool on a third floor balcony. Since I've recently installed Sims 3 Ambitions, the pool had to go to make room for a laundry room.

[image: Washer]

Every now and then one of the Sims on the lot gets stuck in a loop, however, adding the "**Swim**" action to their queue. The icon immediately disappears because there is obviously no route to the pool, leaving the Sim in question to mumble something random or do some stretches before repeating the attempt at finding the pool. Usually this will continue until I manually interrupt the Sim, or until one of their *other* needs takes precedence.

[image: Swim]

Is this a known issue? Is there an easy fix?
I'm running version 1.22.9.

What I've tried so far:

- Restarting the game
- Clearing the caches
- Creating a new pool elsewhere on the lot
- Building a new pool on the same spot at the deleted pool
- Deleting all floor tiles where the pool used to be

Comment: You could try moving the family out of the neighborhood, then back in.  I think that resets wishes and relationships, though.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. Hope I won't have to resort to that, though. @Maxpm

Comment: can you add in a new pool?

Comment: @Xantec: I've tried it, but they still keep trying the old pool from time to time.

Comment: I'll try building a new pool where the old one used to be, see if that helps.

Comment: That didn't help either.

Comment: Seeing as this still doesn't have an answer, you could try making a copy of your neighborhood and then moving the family out and in.  If that doesn't work, at least you still have the old copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a backup of your saves and then, reinstall everything.

And then, recover the backup to it's place and test.

If still with the problem:

1. Your lot or neighborhood got a problem/bug and needs to reset (Erase).
2. Check if there's an update for the game. It should help.
3. Something really strange happened and i can't help you :P

Answer (score 0):

Reset the lot first. Even if you do a complete backup and reinstall- you're still saving the game in a state where the sim is looking for his old pool. After the reinstall you're just putting the save file back where he will still be looking for it.
You should be able to reset the lot by Shft clicking on the mailbox.
taking a trip (assuming you have world adventures) will reset your sim, but not neccessarily your lot.
If you know about mods I would recommend Master Controller to you. You will never have another sims problem you cant fix.